# Advanced Rest Client with ZOHO: POST verb

Tags: html, rest, api, zoho

I have a simple form with one text field and a submit button in ZOHO.

```
<input type="text" name="Name" value="Albie">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

I am trying to enter a value using the Advanced Rest Application (Google Apps). 
[image: Image:]

Here's the same code written in the app:

```
<form method="POST" action="https://creator.zoho.com/api/anansrivastava/xml/rest/form/FormA/record/add/">
<input type="hidden" name ="authtoken" value="92f51989c8fcb3988a9734d11f056dc2">
<input type="hidden" name ="Scope" id="scope" value="creatorapi">
<input type="text" name="Name" value="Gary">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

My URL:

```
https://creator.zoho.com/api/anansrivastava/xml/rest/form/FormA/record/add/
```

The URL I have provided is written in their documentation. It's a POST only URL.  The code that I have written is also from their documentation, word to word. Obviously, I have used my own authentication token. When I click `SEND`, this is the response I get:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
    400: BAD REQUEST 
    <response>
    <code>2945</code>
    <message>XSS_DETECTED</message>
    </response>
```

The code `2945` is the code for an `Invalid Ticket` error. I tried generating a new AuthToken but the the error did not go away. I simply cannot understand what is wrong here. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Links to ZOHO documentation:

1. https://www.zoho.com/creator/help/api/prerequisites/generate-auth-token.html
2. https://www.zoho.com/creator/help/api/rest-api/rest-api-add-records.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to use as a payload:

authtoken=92f51989c8fcb3988a9734d11f056dc2&scope=creatorapi&Name=Peter

Comment: I have placed token like `authtoken=mykey` and tried to send a `GET` request but it didn't helped me out